# PostgreSQL stored procedure using iBatis

Tags: postgresql, ibatis, plpgsql

The error occurred while applying a parameter map:

```
--- Check the newSubs-InlineParameterMap.
--- Check the statement (query failed).
--- Cause:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:
ERROR: wrong record type supplied in RETURN NEXT Where:
PL/pgSQL function "getnewsubs" line 34 at return next
```

the function detail is as below....

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getnewsubs(timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone, integer)
  RETURNS SETOF record AS
$BODY$declare
v_fromdt alias for $1;
v_todt alias for $2;
v_domno alias for $3;
v_cursor refcursor;
v_rec record;
v_cpno bigint;
v_actno int;
v_actname varchar(50);
v_actid varchar(100);
v_cpntypeid varchar(100);
v_mrp double precision;
v_domname varchar(100);
v_usedt timestamp without time zone;
v_expirydt timestamp without time zone;
v_createdt timestamp without time zone;
v_ctno int;
v_phone varchar;
begin
open v_cursor for select cpno,c.actno,usedt from cpnusage c inner join account s on s.actno=c.actno where usedt >= $1 and usedt < $2 and validdomstat(s.domno,v_domno) order by c.usedt;
fetch v_cursor into v_cpno,v_actno,v_usedt;
while found
loop
if isactivation(v_cpno,v_actno,v_usedt) IS TRUE  then
select into v_actno,v_actname,v_actid,v_cpntypeid,v_mrp,v_domname,v_ctno,v_cpno,v_usedt,v_expirydt,v_createdt,v_phone a.actno,a.actname as name,a.actid as actid,c.descr as cpntypeid,l.mrp as mrp,s.domname as domname,c.ctno as ctno,b.cpno,b.usedt,b.expirydt,d.createdt,a.phone from account a
inner join cpnusage b on a.actno=b.actno
inner join cpn d on b.cpno=d.cpno
inner join cpntype c on d.ctno=c.ctno
inner join ssgdom s on a.domno=s.domno
left join price_class l ON l.price_class_id=b.price_class_id
where validdomstat(a.domno,v_domno) and b.cpno=v_cpno and b.actno=v_actno;

select into v_rec v_actno,v_actname,v_actid,v_cpntypeid,v_mrp,v_domname,v_ctno,v_cpno,v_usedt,v_expirydt,v_createdt,v_phone;
return next v_rec;
end if;

fetch v_cursor into v_cpno,v_actno,v_usedt;
end loop;
return ;
end;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
ALTER FUNCTION getnewsubs(timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone, integer) OWNER TO radius
```

If I run the function from the console it runs fine and gives the correct response.  But when used through java it causes the above error.

Answer (score 1):

Immediate cause of the error: The datatype of one or more these variables `v_cpno,v_actno,v_usedt` does not match the corresponding columns in the tables `cpnusage` and `account`.

More generally, your plpgsql function is needlessly complicated and obscure. Could be written with a fraction of the code. I simplified to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getnewsubs(timestamp, timestamp, integer)
  RETURNS TABLE (
     actno      int
    ,actname    text
    ,actid      text
    ,cpntypeid  text
    ,mrp        double precision
    ,domname    text
    ,ctno       int
    ,cpno       bigint
    ,usedt      timestamp without time zone
    ,expirydt   timestamp without time zone
    ,createdt   timestamp without time zone
    ,phone      text) AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    r   record;
BEGIN

FOR r IN
    SELECT cpno, c.actno, usedt
    FROM   cpnusage c
    JOIN   account s ON s.actno = c.actno
    WHERE  usedt >= $1
    AND    usedt <  $2
    AND    validdomstat(s.domno, $3)
    ORDER  BY c.usedt;

LOOP
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT a.actno
        ,a.actname
        ,a.actid
        ,c.descr        --  as cpntypeid
        ,l.mrp
        ,s.domname
        ,c.ctno
        ,b.cpno
        ,b.usedt
        ,b.expirydt
        ,d.createdt
        ,a.phone
    FROM   account a
    JOIN   cpnusage b ON a.actno = b.actno
    JOIN   cpn d ON b.cpno = d.cpno
    JOIN   cpntype c ON d.ctno = c.ctno
    JOIN   ssgdom s ON a.domno = s.domno
    LEFT   JOIN price_class l ON l.price_class_id = b.price_class_id
    WHERE  validdomstat(a.domno, $3)
    AND    b.cpno = r.cpno
    AND    b.actno = r.actno;
    AND    isactivation(r.cpno,r.actno,r.usedt) IS TRUE
END LOOP;

RETURN;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
ALTER FUNCTION getnewsubs(timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone, integer) OWNER TO radius
```

Could probably be simplified to a single `RETURN QUERY`. But I have beaten this dead horse quite enough.